# Non thread safe Rails 5 App in elasticbeanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, puma

I am deploying my Rails 5.2 app in elastic beanstalk with puma as application server and Nginx as default by Elastic Beanstalk.

I am facing an issue of a race condition. After I check more details in container instance I found this:

```html
#example /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/conf/pumaconf.rb
directory '/var/app/current'
threads 8, 32
workers %x(grep -c processor /proc/cpuinfo)
bind 'unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock'
pidfile '/var/run/puma/puma.pid'
stdout_redirect '/var/log/puma/puma.log', '/var/log/puma/puma.log', true
daemonize false
```

As seen here the number of workers is equal to the number of my CPU core.

However, in Heroku.com we can do this:

```html
# config/puma.rb

workers Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 2)
threads_count = Integer(ENV['RAILS_MAX_THREADS'] || 5)
threads threads_count, threads_count

preload_app!

rackup      DefaultRackup
port        ENV['PORT']     || 3000
environment ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'development'

on_worker_boot do
  # Worker specific setup for Rails 4.1+
  # See: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server#on-worker-boot
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

How can I lower down the number of threads and increase the number of workers in elastic beanstalk? by taking into account that I have a load balancer enabled and the config above is managed by elastic beanstalk.

In the case of Heroku I can manage with puma.rb, however in elastic beanstalk I don't see any other approach besides changing the file

```
/opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/conf/pumaconf.rb
```

manually. Manually modification will cause issues when the number of instances scaling down or up.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, if you've resolved your issue. I had a similar issue and I resolved it using the .ebextensions.

You can create a new pumaconf.rb file on your config directory in your code. Then in the .ebextensions directory, create a file that will copy out the new pumaconf.rb and replace the default pumaconf.rb.

Also, if you are going about it this way. In your .ebextensions code, use this path for your new file

/var/app/ondeck/config/pumaconf.rb

and not

/var/app/current/config/pumaconf.rb

Because using the latter one, wont copy out your latest pumaconf.rb

```
cp /var/app/ondeck/config/pumaconf.rb /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/conf/pumaconf.rb
```